Kestrel in ServiceFabric not firing CancellationToken event
I have an endpoint in an on-premis stateless service fabric Kestrel instance that receives a CancellationToken, but when a request is terminated, the token is not cancelled until 2 minutes have passed, even if the Postman request is terminated (or the Swagger page is closed) immediately after the request is made. Am I doing something wrong? The received token is not default, but it doesn't seem to be the one from the connection, either, just a generic timeout token.
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class MyController : Controller
    {
        ...
        [HttpGet("TestCancellation")]
        public async Task TestCancellation(CancellationToken token)
        {
            if (token == default)
            {
                LoggingContext.Message("TestCancellation NoToken");
                return;
            }

            var i = 0;
            LoggingContext.Message("TestCancellation Start");
            while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                LoggingContext.Message($"TestCancellation Running {i}");
                await Task.Delay(1000, token);
                i++;
            }
            LoggingContext.Message("TestCancellation End");
        }
    }

How do I get the token for a terminated connection?
